# overflow-y scroll doesn't move in react-autosuggest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, scroll

I found the first solution to activated a scroll, but it didn't work for me. ul block does not scroll down when switching elements using the down arrow on the keyboard.
my version react-autosuggest is "^10.1.0"

```
.react-autosuggest__suggestions-list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-autosuggest-forked-4519do?file=/src/styles.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by replacing the .react-autosuggest__suggestions-list class to #react-autowhatever-1